# Docker is not running when run curl command to create new laravel project

Tags: laravel, docker, curl

I just start learning laravel, and follow the tutorial from https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation "Getting started on Windows" .
I manage to install Docker Desktop and COnfigured to use WSL2 Backend.

When I run the command `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash` to create laravel application directory from cmd, this warning come out `Docker is not running`.

I run curl using command prompt. (cmd).

Update:

So, I run the command in Windows Terminal:.

```
PS E:\Play> curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

Here is the response I get:

```
cmdlet Invoke-WebRequest at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Uri:
```

Any Idea what to do?

Comment: can you elaborate how are you executing curl? using docker exec? did you check if Docker service was active?

Comment: Docker is running. When I type 'docker --version' , reply 'Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61'. Maybe its something in here > https://laravel.build/example-app ?

Comment: Seems to me that the script is bash for Unix, did you try to execute the script without using curl? I mean download the script locally and try to execute it locally

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try to explicitly [enable integration](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/) with your distro in Docker settings:
[image]

After that relaunch your WSL2 terminal & try again. That should help.
You can also open https://laravel.build/example-app in a browser & check what commands the script is running: and run them manually to check the output for any errors.

Comment: I also had to reboot my computer after doing this. Restarting Docker wasn't enough.

Comment: Somehow when docker was in the list of startup apps in windows 10, ubuntu was auto recognizing that it was started but then i disabled it from startup apps, it was showing that Docker is not running. 
After I checked ubuntu switch which is in above image and restarted docker and ubuntu app both, it worked afterwards.

Answer (score 8):

For those who are using Ubuntu or Debian can check this guide out on how to install and configure Docker.

```
sudo snap install docker 
sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami) 


sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: `chmod` did the trick for me on a plain Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install a linux distro, and then in Windows Terminal create a new tab for the linux distro and run the command there, not in a windows powershell tab.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are running `curl` command on your distro. Use [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) app and open a new tab as WSL2 (your distro).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

I guess you are using ubuntu or debian.
chmod will do the trick here.

Answer (score 0):

For my Ubuntu 22.04LTS I needed to restart the machine after installing Docker-Desktop, then I set the permissions to 666, as described here.

> `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`